# Wordpress Query formcraft table echo fields to screen

Tags: php, wordpress

First time working with `Wordpress`. I am looking to get a random row from a `formcraft` table so I can publish the winner of a draw from a bunch of registrations on a page.

The content I want from the `formcraft` table is stored like this in a column called `content` in a table called `wp_formcraft_3_submissions`:

```
[
{\"label\":\"Name\",\"value\":\"Annette\",\"identifier\":\"field1\",\"type\":\"oneLineText\",\"page\":1,\"page_name\":\"Step 1\",\"width\":\"100%\",\"altLabel\":\"Name\"},
{\"label\":\"Company Name\",\"value\":\"My Co \",\"identifier\":\"field3\",\"type\":\"oneLineText\",\"page\":1,\"page_name\":\"Step 1\",\"width\":\"100%\",\"altLabel\":\"Company Name\"},
{\"label\":\"Email\",\"value\":\"annette@email.com\",\"identifier\":\"field6\",\"type\":\"email\",\"page\":1,\"page_name\":\"Step 1\",\"width\":\"100%\",\"altLabel\":\"Email\"}
]
```

I am trying to pull a random row, then publish `name`, `company name`.

I am stuck, and `wordpress` is not logging any errors though I have turned on error logging. I am doing this via a `shortcode`. I would like to echo the contents on the screen to start with, but ultimately, echo just the three fields.

```
function wa_awards_winner() {

    global $wpdb;

    $sql = $wpdb->query("
    SELECT *
    FROM wp_formcraft_3_submissions
    ORDER BY RAND()
    LIMIT 1
    ");

    $result = $wpdb->get_results( $sql );

    if ( ! $result ) { return false; }

    $winner = json_encode($result[0]->content);

    echo $winner;

}

add_shortcode( 'get_wa_awards_winner', 'wa_awards_winner' );
```

Untilmately I am trying to get these values like this but it is not working:

```
// NAME
echo '<h3 class="col">' . $winner[0][0] . '</h3>';

// COMPANY NAME
echo '<h3 class="col">' . $winner[1][0] . '</h3>';

// EMAIL
echo '<h3 class="col">' . $winner[2][0] . '</h3>';
```

Appreciate any help. Thanks.

---

Trying suggestion below like this:

```
$winner = json_decode(stripslashes($result[0]->content),true);

echo '<div style="color:white;">' . print_r($winner, true) . '</div>';
```

I get;

```
[13-Jun-2019 12:28:25 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 0 in /var/www/site.com/wp-content/themes/dp-click-Child/functions.php on line 30
[13-Jun-2019 12:28:25 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'content' of non-object in /var/www/site.com/wp-content/themes/dp-click-Child/functions.php on line 30
```

---

This works thanks to suggestion below:

```
$sql = "
    SELECT *
    FROM wp_formcraft_3_submissions
    ORDER BY RAND()
    LIMIT 1
";

$result = $wpdb->get_results( $sql );
```

I then try and access the info lke this:

```
$winner = json_decode(stripslashes($result[0]->content),true);

echo var_dump($winner);

echo '<h3 style="color: white;">NAME: ' . $winner[0]["Name"] . '</h3>';
echo '<h3 style="color: white;">COMPANY: ' . $winner[1]["Company Name"] . '</h3>';
echo '<h3 style="color: white;">EMAIL: ' . $winner[2]["Email"] . '</h3>';
```

The `var_dump` returns:

```
array(3) { [0]=> array(8) { ["label"]=> string(4) "Name" ["value"]=> string(14) "Annette" ["identifier"]=> string(6) "field1" ["type"]=> string(11) "oneLineText" ["page"]=> int(1) ["page_name"]=> string(6) "Step 1" ["width"]=> string(4) "100%" ["altLabel"]=> string(4) "Name" } [1]=> array(8) { ["label"]=> string(12) "Company Name" ["value"]=> string(19) "My Company" ["identifier"]=> string(6) "field3" ["type"]=> string(11) "oneLineText" ["page"]=> int(1) ["page_name"]=> string(6) "Step 1" ["width"]=> string(4) "100%" ["altLabel"]=> string(12) "Company Name" } [2]=> array(8) { ["label"]=> string(5) "Email" ["value"]=> string(20) "annette@email.com" ["identifier"]=> string(6) "field6" ["type"]=> string(5) "email" ["page"]=> int(1) ["page_name"]=> string(6) "Step 1" ["width"]=> string(4) "100%" ["altLabel"]=> string(5) "Email" } }
```

But my variables return empty:

```
NAME:
COMPANY NAME:
EMAIL:
```

Comment: Undefined offset and trying to get property means your `$result` variable isn't as you expected. For easier debugging move it outside your shortcode and test `$result` with `var_dump()`

Comment: Man, I love Laravel! This WP stuff is a whole new world. How do I move the variable out of the shortcode?

Comment: For all future tasks you do under WP you may easily debug this way:
1) In your current (active) theme folder create a file e.g. mytestpage.php
2) Put this comment at the beginning of the file `Template name: My Test Page` (it's a php comment, so it's with // or /* */)
3) Put any code you like inside that file, e.g. `echo 'hello world';`
4) Go to admin panel, create a new page and **choose template My Test Page**
5) Visit page

Comment: Hi @GMarco, thanks. Great suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to make "stripslashing" and to turn the given string to JSON data. Then you need to decode it, not encode.

Here it is:

```
 $winner = json_decode(stripslashes($result[0]->content),true);
 echo $winner[0]["value"];
```

And one more thing. $wpdb->query can't be used inside get_results. Remove those and use this instead

```
   $sql = "
    SELECT *
    FROM wp_formcraft_3_submissions
    ORDER BY RAND()
    LIMIT 1
    ";

   $result = $wpdb->get_results( $sql );
```

Comment: Hi @Elvin Haci, see my update above. Thanks or the suggestion.

Comment: are you sure your SQL query is correct? f.e. table name should be wp_formcraft_3_submissions, but you wrote wp_formcraft_3_forms.   If this doesn't help either, try to var_dump($result); and see what it prints.

Comment: Oops, copy paste mistake, fixed myquestion. Yes, the table name is correct. I can use `MySQLWorkbench` and see a row in the table.

Comment: So this do a var_dump($result); please, and let me know what it prints. (after $result = $wpdb->get_results( $sql );)

Comment: i have noticed another error and this is why your code doesn't work. i have updated my answer, check it

Comment: The `var_dump` returns `array(0) { }`. If I cut and paste the query into `MySQLWorkbench` then I get the expected row.

Comment: Love your work! Finally see a record come back! But now I am struggling to access the key value pairs in each object. See my update above. Many thanks!